# Angular4 AOT with Semantic Less not working

Tags: angular, semantic-ui, angular-aot

I have a strange issue when using angular4 with semantic less (and semantic for angular2 from vladotesanovic).
When I'm launching my project (npm start) everything works fine.

But when I'm launching with AOT compilation (npm run build:aot -> num run server:prod):

This is **sm-select**

The not working example in below image :

[image]
This is example repo:

https://github.com/fpmk/ngx-semantic-less-webpack

Comment: Any errors on build or in your console? Without a reproducable plunkr there's not much we can do to help..

Comment: No erros during compile. And no errors in browser's console. Actually i can't imagine how to do this with plunkr.

Answer (score 0):

Removed semantic from project and implemented needed components by copying it from distribs. I think the problem is in ng-semantic itself.